# javascript strange loader behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange behavior with a page loader, the first time i load the page appear and desappear when finish to load, next time when i don't load the entire page but only fetch data each 30 seconds from db to update map data the loader not appear anymore. Making debugging console.log work right always and the loader start to work properly when i remove the ajax calls adding inside loadTracking a settimeout to hide loader. I think something wrong on ajax call but i don't understand what. thanks

loader div after body

```
<div id="loader"></div>
```

css of loader

```
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
```

then i have a javascript code to manage a google maps

```
    function initMap() {
// init of map 
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
            if (!this.loaded) {
              this.loaded = true;
              displayAndWatch();
            }
          });
    function displayAndWatch() {
            loadTracking();
            if (boundsExists == 1) {
              map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }
            updateTracking();
          }
    
          function updateTracking() {
            setInterval(loadTracking, 30000);
          }

function loadTracking() {
        $('#loader').show();
        console.log('Start loading...');

$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          url: "/schedules/tracking-data/",
          complete: function () {
            console.log('End loading...');
            $('#loader').hide();
          },
success: function(data){
// some operations
}
});

// i have other 3 ajax call inside this function but only the first have the loader hide
}
    
    }
```

Comment: ok, so where do you set your `this.loaded` to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

i have found the problem, setting async: true all the ajax calls it work like a sharm i don't know why but it works.